# handling Application_Error in ASP.NET app's global.asax

Tags: asp.net

I wish to send mail to an administrator when the application crashes.
So I simply do this in `global.asax`:

```
void Application_error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendMessageToAdministarator(Server.GetLastError().ToString());
}
```

But actually many times `Application_Error` is called even though the application won't crash.

And I wish to send mail to admin ONLY when the application crashed.

Also, do I have a simple way to lift the application back on?

I'm looking for the simplest solution.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

What kind of errors are send when the application is not crashed? You could check the type of exception and don't send emails on the exceptions that don't crash the app (for example a redirect can throw the ThreadAbortException which I manually filter in code):

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    if (ex is ThreadAbortException)
        return;
    Logger.Error(LoggerType.Global, ex, "Exception");
    Response.Redirect("unexpectederror.htm");
}
```

You could add a redirect to an error page with a message for the user that an error has occured and some links to relevant pages in the site. This is for the 'lift the application back on' - I hope this is what you wanted.

Also you might look into logging with log4net which can also log errors on the server *and* send emails on errors.

Comment: Thank you very much. What do you mean by "manually filter in code" ? also, one error that I constanly getting is some 
System.Web.HttpException: File does not exist.
  at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context)... but that doesn't do any noticeable harm

Comment: I updated the answer with a code example. You can replace ThreadAbortException with HttpException. Or add multiple checks there for more exception types.