# Should you use the method Application_Error in your global.asax in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, global-asax, error-logging

I know that in ASP.NET people typically put a protected method called "Application_Error" in their global.asax file inorder to handle say, [logging of exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434859/handling-applicationerror-in-asp-net-apps-global-asax).

My question is, is this an ASP.NET only thing, or does it work equally well in ASP.NET MVC?  Is it an ASP.NET MVC best practice or not?

Comment: You can use the Application_Error() method but it won't work as you expect. Here is another SO question where we are discussing the problem further: http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2009/12/iis-7-managed-pipeline-mode-globalasax.html

Answer (score 5):

You should be using the Exception Filter to handle exceptions in your controllers. You do this by adding the [HandleError] attribute to the controller action. Further information can be found at: on the [MS MVP MVC Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2009/02/06/the-mvc-platform-handling-errors.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Application_Error block but [better yet, use ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/MVC).  It's a lovely error logging tool (and I'm kind of surprised that it hasn't been bundled in with ASP.Net/ASP.Net MVC).

If you've never used it, it captures the yellow screen of death and a whole mess of environmental variables so that you can review the errors that you've caught.

Along with this, all of our controllers inherit from a controller base class that's decorated with the [HandleError] attribute that Wolfwyrd linked to so that we get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score -2):

Anything that works in ASP.Net works in ASP.Net MVC, and I do mean anything. Including your old-style ASPX pages complete with code-behind and Viewstate.

Comment: Everything from ASP.NET is _supposed_ to work in MVC3. Unfortunately, one of the things that doesn't have the same behavior between frameworks is the Application_Error() method: http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2009/12/iis-7-managed-pipeline-mode-globalasax.html.

Comment: This is completely untrue and misleading. There is plenty of stuff that doesn't work in MVC. Another example is Server.Transfer.