# Why would ASP.NET not enter Application_Error in Global.asax.cs when throwing an HttpRequestValidationException?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, exception

I am trying to prevent having this raw error appear on the screen when the user enters e.g. pointed brackets in an input field:

> [System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException] A potentially dangerous
>   Request.Form value was detected from the client (Message="

I've learned in [posts like this one](http://romsteady.blogspot.com/2007/06/how-to-catch-httprequestvalidationexcep.html) that I should be able to catch and handle this error in the `void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)` method in the `Global.asax.cs` file, e.g. I have this code:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

    if (ex is HttpRequestValidationException)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.StatusCode = 200;
        Response.Write(@"<html><body>HTML is not allowed.</body></html>");
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

But regardless of what code I have in the `void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)` method, code execution does not enter it, but rather simply outputs the raw error as before.

**What could be preventing code execution from entering the `void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)` method?**

Note: I don't have custom errors set to RemoteOnly in my `Web.config` as seems to be the issue in [Is global.asax Application_Error event not fired if custom errors are turned on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111387/is-global-asax-application-error-event-not-fired-if-custom-errors-are-turned-on)

Comment: Have you tried adding a breakpoint to `Response.Clear();`? Is it getting hit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is global.asax Application\_Error event not fired if custom errors are turned on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111387/is-global-asax-application-error-event-not-fired-if-custom-errors-are-turned-on)

Comment: If you have any other error handler (Filters or Middleware) check to see if they are not intercepting the error in the pipeline and clearing it before it reaches that handler. `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;`

Comment: @mjwills, I have a breakpoint at `Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();` and it doesn't even get to that point.

Comment: @mjwills, regarding the possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111387/is-global-asax-application-error-event-not-fired-if-custom-errors-are-turned-on, I don't have custom errors set to RemoteOnly in Web.config as seems to be the issue in that question.

Comment: I can catch execution in `Global.asax.cs` in the method `Application_AuthenticateRequest` after the form post, but when I step through, it never enters `Application_Error`.