# Accessing the exception if custom redirection redirects to a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, error-handling

I am using MVC4, and would like to be able to throw HttpExceptions from a ontroller, and handle those in a seperate controler.

I have set up `<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Error"/>` for this. This works, but in my controller I would like to be able to access the exception.

Preferably I would like to have two modes:

1. Handle instances of HttpException, so that from a controller I can throw a HttpException and have it handled accordingly
2. Handle all other errors.

in case of the first, I would like to present the useragent with the appropriate status code, and possibly a view. In case of the second I want to present the useragent with status 500, and show a default view with an optional message.

For this, I think I need to access the exception data - at least, I can't think of any other proper way to do this.

What is the proper way to set this up? I know there are plethoria of other questions on error handling in MVC, yet none seem to answer these questions.

Comment: http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/5/exception_handling_in_asp_net_mvc

Answer (score 1):

```
 but in my controller I would like to be able to access the exception.
```

Have you tried [Server.GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.getlasterror.aspx):

```
Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
```

Server.GetLastError() - should be used in Application_Error in global.asax, in that case you can handle last error like [described here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1751599.aspx/1), besides you should remove

```
filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
```

in FilterConfig.cs

for more info look at:

[Application_Error not firing when customerrors = "On"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508415/application-error-not-firing-when-customerrors-on)

[ASP.NET custom error page - Server.GetLastError() is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343014/asp-net-custom-error-page-server-getlasterror-is-null)

http://www.secretgeek.net/custom_errors_mvc.asp

http://devstuffs.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/how-to-use-customerrors-in-asp-net-mvc-2/

Comment: Alas, `Server.GetLastError` returns `null`