# Application_Error not hit when RemoteOnly

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, web-config, custom-errors

I want to write custom errors and unexpected errors via Global.asax.

In that method I  use :  `var ex = Server.GetLastError();` to obtain the error which ocurred.

However, this code is not hit (or fired) when I set web.config to ErrorMode RemoteOnly.
It only works when it's set to Off.

Why is this?

```
try
   {
 var   sd = db.GetDetails().Single();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
    //some function here followed by a throw.
    throw;
   }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application\_Error not firing when customerrors = "On"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508415/application-error-not-firing-when-customerrors-on)

Comment: @sohaiby MVC.. really?