# Why is data not stored in database from stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Entity Framework and I'm trying to store some data in SQL Server using this stored procedure:

```
create procedure [dbo].[Sp_OrderList]
    @OrderId int,
    @OrderName varchar(50),
    @OrderData datetime 
As
Begin
    Insert into OrderList (OrderId, OrderName, OrderDate)    
    values (@OrderId, @OrderName, @OrderData)
End
```

C# code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage SaveCountry(OrderList cnt)
{
    OrderList Cntrcountr = new OrderList();
    Cntrcountr.OrderId = cnt.OrderId;
    Cntrcountr.OrderName = cnt.OrderName;
    Cntrcountr.OrderDate = cnt.OrderDate;

    var param = new SqlParameter("",Cntrcountr);
    var country = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Sp_OrderList", Cntrcountr);

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, country);
}
```

I'm getting an error

> 500  Internal server error

Please help me - what's my mistake?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: You should learn how to figure out what the error is. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768715/application-error-in-global-asax-not-catching-errors-in-webapi/28769915#28769915).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your stored procedure doesn't actually return any data you should use the `ExecuteSqlCommand` method. Try this:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    "EXEC Sp_OrderList @OrderId, @OrderName, @OrderData",
    new SqlParameter("@OrderId", cnt.OrderId),
    new SqlParameter("@OrderName", cnt.OrderName), 
    new SqlParameter("@OrderData", cnt.OrderData));
```

Comment: Getting Error as  Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '@OrderName'.

Answer (score 0):

`Database.SqlQuery` takes the sql and then parameters as an array. You are passing in a complex objects and expecting the properties to be translated into parameters. See [Database.SqlQuery documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery%60%601%28System.String,System.Object[]%29).

```
public HttpResponseMessage SaveCountry(OrderList cnt)
{
    var country = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("exec Sp_OrderList @OrderId, @OrderName, @OrderData", cnt.OrderId, cnt.OrderName, cnt.OrderDate);

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, country);
}
```

That said the reason for the 500 status is because your server code has experienced an unhandled Exception. You should add logging OR learn how to debug your server side code so you can inspect the Exception when it occurs.

Comment: Here we r not supplying any Columns Then How can Its work when i exceute above query sql Performance Generate exec sp_executesql N'Sp_OrderList',N'@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(1),@p2 datetime',@p0=123,@p1=N'q',@p2='2015-01-01 00:00:00' Error as Procedure or function 'Sp_OrderList' expects parameter '@OrderId', which was not supplied.