# ASP .NET MVC 500 Internal Server Error - on Get and Post - same application / different servers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, iis-8

I'm trying to help our System Admins here, so please don't beat me up for my lack of knowledge.  We can run the application locally and we can build and deploy to our Test Server and the application reports work as expected.  But when we deploy to our Production Server, many of the Get and Post Ajax calls are getting 500 errors.  Essentially, all reports run everywhere EXCEPT on the Production Server.

This is an ASP .NET MVC application with the views being Razor HTML and JavaScript.  The model, controllers, and services are all in C#.  IIS 8.5 web server and SQL Server for the database.

I've Googled and tried everything I could find.  More detailed errors show us the service call that fails along with the parameters and all looks good.  Again the application reports run fine in all environments other than the Production Server.  Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and what we should be looking at to resolve the issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just turn off custom errors in the web.config file

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off">
</system.web>
```

and then open up the development tools in a browser during one of the GET requests and replay the GET yourself.  Should get the exact error message back.

Comment: customErrors are off.  We don't use custom errors at all.

Comment: @Patricia So then what is the error returned?  If all you see is a 500 error and no details, check the Application event log.  Usually when there isn't an error displayed, it can mean the web.config file can't be parsed or there is a server error happening elsewhere.  Do a request and then check that Application event log.

Comment: Before I added Application_Error() method in Global.asax.cs and it was **NOT** being hit when there was an error. By turning off customErrors, the method get hit and I get full detail error in the method using breakpoint. More details : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768715/application-error-in-global-asax-not-catching-errors-in-webapi)

Thanks for help @Josh

Answer (score 0):

It took us all day to figure out that one of the parameter tables did not have the appropriate permissions.  Which would explain why some reports ran while others consistently returned a 500 error.