# Not seeing any trace or exceptions in Insights

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, azure-application-insights

**TL;DR:** This post could be titled "Why do all my Insights calls get logged as '*A task was canceled.*'?"

I am trying to use `Application Insights` to log errors from our `ASP.NET web API 2` application but they are clearly not being logged. I have an Insights key and this is clearly being used because I can see `REQUEST` and `DEPENDENCY` entries, however there are no `EXCEPTION` or `TRACE` entries created by my custom code.

I am wondering if I am not seeing globally thrown exceptions because I don't have any controller-level exception handling - though the code below should, I believe, be enough to catch all exceptions and log them (when they are not more locally caught and handled)...

Global.asax.cs:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = EnvironmentHelper.InsightsKey;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }

    protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception appException = Server.GetLastError();
        var ai = new TelemetryClient();
        ai.TrackException(appException);
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new InsightsExceptionLogger());

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new InsightsExceptionFilter());
    }
}
```

InsightsExceptionLogger.cs:

```
public class InsightsExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        if (context != null && context.Exception != null)
        {
            var ai = new TelemetryClient();
            ai.TrackException(context.Exception);
        }

        base.Log(context);
    }
}

public class InsightsExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context != null && context.Exception != null)
        {
            var ai = new TelemetryClient();
            ai.TrackException(context.Exception);
        }
    }

    public override Task OnExceptionAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (context != null && context.Exception != null)
        {
            var ai = new TelemetryClient();
            ai.TrackException(context.Exception);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Example Controller.cs:

```
[CookieAuthentication, CookieSlidingExpiration, InsightsExceptionFilter]
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    private TelemetryClient ai = null;

    public SomeController()
    {
        TelemetryClient ai = new TelemetryClient();
    }

    [Route("api/v1/SomeEndpoint"), HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetSomeEndpoint([FromUri]string aParameter)
    {
        ai.TrackTrace("test trace");
        throw new Exception("test exception");
    }
}
```

The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28769915/71376) to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768715/application-error-in-global-asax-not-catching-errors-in-webapi) is similar to my problem, but I am not seeing any trace statement or deliberate exception logged in Insights.

What I do see it a lot of is this log entry:

```
A task was canceled.
```

With this exception:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
```

Though I do not understand how/why my deliberately thrown exceptions would be translated to this (if that is what is happening) or why my `TrackTrace()` calls are not appearing in the Insights log.

Under that exception I see this stack trace:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult+<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext (System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult+<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext (System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult+<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext (System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that this whole mess has been the result of one incorrectly assigned variable. Very frustrating, but an easy fix. This was discovered when I removed the deliberate exception throwing from the controller methods and still logged the problem instead of trace messages - those should have been simple to receive. The faulty code is the constructor:

Example Controller.cs:

```
[CookieAuthentication, CookieSlidingExpiration, InsightsExceptionFilter]
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    private TelemetryClient ai = null;

    public SomeController()
    {
        TelemetryClient ai = new TelemetryClient(); // WHY LOCAL???
    }

    [Route("api/v1/SomeEndpoint"), HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetSomeEndpoint([FromUri]string aParameter)
    {
        ai.TrackTrace("test trace");
        throw new Exception("test exception");
    }
}
```

Of course, changing this to...

Example Controller.cs:

```
[CookieAuthentication, CookieSlidingExpiration, InsightsExceptionFilter]
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    private TelemetryClient ai = null;

    public SomeController()
    {
        ai = new TelemetryClient();
    }

    [Route("api/v1/SomeEndpoint"), HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetSomeEndpoint([FromUri]string aParameter)
    {
        ai.TrackTrace("test trace");
        throw new Exception("test exception");
    }
}
```

...solved the problem and I am now receiving trace statements as intended.