# Application_Error event of global.asax is not firing on production server but working on DEV and QA server

Tags: asp.net, global-asax, application-error

Application_Error event is not firing on production server, this production server having Load Balancer. Application_Error event is firing and running well on QA and DEV server only issue is there on production server.
Please help.

Comment: I'm guessing a difference in the web.config customerrors value  between the environments. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508415/application-error-not-firing-when-customerrors-on)

Comment: it was some issue in code written in Application_Error event , i have fixed it  now its working fine.

Comment: @user2781180 Could you please elaborate a bit further on what the issue was? I am having a similar issue where Application_Start runs perfectly fine on DEV and QA environments, but it doesn't run on the UAT server.