# ASP.NET SessionState timeout

Tags: asp.net, session, timeout, session-state, inproc

I use ASP.NET website on IIS7 where in web.config I have:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"></sessionState>
```

But session doesn't keep 20 minutes, it works very strange, sometimes it expires in 1 minute or less, sometimes just redirect to other page. I need use mode="InProc".

Who can help me, what is wrong and how to resolve this problem? 
Thanks!

Comment: Acutally, you don't even need SessionState tag (Comment out the SessionState tag, and see what happens). By default, time out is 20 mintues. Look like somewhere in our code is clearing the session.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx

Comment: Here at Network Solution we had a long day with this issue, and finally we expertise and solved this specific problem (Session expiring and specified timeout is ignored) at server configuration level.

Result of our work is a shared server where hosted created apps can be always-logged, thanks to our server config scripts (made in years of expertise), preconfigured also with the SessionState DB custom database if you want, the ideal for Windows-IIS-ASP.NET-MSSQL shared hosting!


Please contact me at marco.marsala AT live.it to see if our solution is applicable in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an application that is throwing unhandled exceptions, the application could recycle. Or, it could recycle because of memory pressure or even just from the wrong settings in IIS. This would cause you to lose session. You can put some logging code in the Application_End Eventhandler in global.asax to check for this condition.

Comment: Probably this is the cause, you may also want to handle [Application_Error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/434859/277290).

Answer (score 0):

Application Pool Recycling?  (IIS setting).

Anyway, you can detect and handle the timeout in the global.asax (session_end), if that helps.