# Debugging Remote ASP.NET Web Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, iis

I am developing a Wp7 application, and I am running into a server exception when calling certain methods. I have access to the server where the services are hosted, but I can't see how I can debug or get more information out of the exception so that I can handle it.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subscribe to the [`Application_Error` event in Global.asax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434859/handling-application-error-in-asp-net-apps-global-asax) that is triggered on each unhandled exception and log the error details.

If you have control over the remote server you could also install the [Remote Debugging Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx) and step through the code.

Comment: You can install it. Simply copy the contents of the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger` folder to the remote server and start the `msvsmon.exe`. Then you can attach a local VS instance to the remote server and debug the code. This obviously assumes that you have deployed the same debugging PDB symbols as the source code you have.