# Send e-mail to webmaster when error on page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling

I have set `<customErrors mode="On"/>` in my web.config. If there is an error on the site the user gets a "user friendly" error message. In the mean time I want to send an e-mail to the myself with the actual error message (so I know exactly what went wrong).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write code to send the mail in the `Application_Error` method of the `Global.asax` file.

[Sample here for using the Application_Error method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434859/handling-application-error-in-asp-net-apps-global-asax).